# Найти предложения, связанные с предыдущим формой слова и сочинительным союзом

Tags: грамматика

> ***Среди предложений 29−36 найдите такое(-ие), которое(-ые) связано(-ы) с
> предыдущим при помощи сочинительного союза и форм(ы) слов(а). Напишите
> номер(а) этого(-их) предложения(-ий).***
>
> (29)Рождается желание глубоко постигнуть, осмыслить явления и
> сопоставить одно явление с другим. (30)Отсюда наш интерес к истории
> искусства, литературы, к биографии создателей гениальных творений, к
> процессу их творчества, к той эпохе, в которую они жили.
>
> (31)Разрозненные впечатления соединяются в общую картину культуры.
> (32)Каждому **явлению** отводится своё место. (33)И каждое **явление**
> оценивается не только само по себе, но и в сопоставлении с другими.
> (34)Значительное, великое мы научаемся отличать от пошлого и
> преходящего. (35)Великие **творения** слушаем, смотрим и перечитываем
> неоднократно. (36)И с каждым разом находим в **творениях** всё больше
> красот.

В ответе:

```
Предложение 33 связано с предыдущим при помощи сочинительного союза И и формы слова «каждому  — каждое».

В предложении 36 союз «и» связывает ОЧ внутри одного предложения.
```

Но почему не 36 предложение? Оно же связано с 35 сочинительным союзом, который соединяет ОЧ (Мы слушаем, смотрим, перечитываем, находим) - разве это не подходит под ответ?

Comment: творения - творениях (35-36)

Comment: Удалите вопрос, пожалуйста. Проблема исчерпана (просто ответы неверные)

Comment: Откуда вы взяли это задание?

Comment: Пояснение.

Предложение 33 связано с предыдущим при помощи сочинительного союза И и форм слова «каждому  — каждое», «явлению» —«явление».

В предложении 36 аналогично: союз И и формы слов «творения»-«творениях».